# A problem V.I. Arnold solved as a primary school student

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question, education, math-history, popular-math

According to a 1995 [interview](http://www.ams.org/notices/199704/arnold.pdf) that Vladimir I. Arnold gave to the *Notices of the AMS*, 
his primary school teacher I.V. Morozkin gave in 1949 (when Arnold was 12 years old) to a Soviet classroom, most likely the 6th grade, the following question

> *Two women started at sunrise and each walked at a constant velocity. One went from $A$ 
>   to $B$ and the other from $B$ to $A$.  They met at noon and, continuing with no stop, 
>   arrived respectively at $B$ at 4 p.m. and at $A$ at 9 p.m. At what time was the sunrise 
>   that day?*

The question is not how to solve this problem, but rather *How to solve this problem using what 12 year old kids know* (or knew during the Soviet era).

**UPDATE.** In the same interview, Arnold also said:

> I spent a whole day thinking on this
>   oldie, and the solution (based on what
>   is now called scaling arguments,
>   dimensional analysis, or toric variety
>   theory, depending on your taste) came
>   as a revelation.

It would be of interest to know how, in Arnold's mind, dimensional analysis and toric varieties are related to this problem.

Comment: Since 12 year old kids know basic algebra, I don't see the challenge.

Comment: Are we assuming that the sun rises simultaneously at $A$ and $B$, and that the clocks at $A$ and $B$ show the same time?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, we must, because otherwise there's not enough information to solve the problem.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Yes it does simultaneously, and the clocks as well have the same time.

Comment: This classic is known as Arnold's Sunrise Problem. A [web search](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22arnold%22+sunrise+noon+time+women+walk) turns up many discussions.

Comment: @dfeuer: We need to assume that they can not solve a quadratic equation.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis: Why do we "need" such an assumption? I'm fairly sure I had seen the quadratic formula at 12, and I don't see how a bright 12-year-old cannot have figured out how to use it.

Comment: The equations I chose led me to an equation of the form $x^2 = $ square number.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Think geometrically...

Comment: @behn: That's definitely simple enough.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis: Do you have a _geometric argument_ that 12-year old Arnold didn't know how to solve quadratics? I'd like to see that.

Comment: You omitted perhaps the most interesting part, Arnold's following remark that "I spent a whole day thinking on this oldie, and the solution (based on what is now called scaling arguments, dimensional analysis, or toric variety theory, depending on your taste) came as a revelation." Many folks wonder about the relationship with toric varieties.

Comment: Most nowadays 12-ers haven't probably studied enough stuff to be able to solve this with h.s. algebra, yet it is not that advanced a problem for that age, though I'd say it is a challenge.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: See the edited version of the question. To me it looks like he has in mind a geometrical proof.

Comment: @BillDubuque: Thanks for the remark. It is added in the edited version of the question.

Comment: @DonAntonio: It seems me that the teacher thought of it as a solvable problem, given what his students were supposed to know.

Comment: The problem can be solved using plain geometry and the concept of ratios. I suspect in Arnold's time, people still taught those ideas to kids. It will not be a surprise the teacher think this problem is appropriate for a 12 year old.

Comment: @achillehui: I think, that's how Arnold solved it.

Comment: Soviet education did not change much between VIA's and my time, and I can confirm that Soviet 12 year olds knew more than enough to do this (either geometrically or algebraically).

Comment: Huh. Just reading the comments, I can tell that my middle school's math was trash compared to whatever you guys had.

Comment: I think it's reasonable to assume that Arnold did not know enough algebra to set up and solve a system of multivariate equations, otherwise it makes no sense to mention the problem in an interview. It would be like that famous anecdote about Gauss ending with "but the previous week, Gauss's uncle had taught him the formula for summing up numbers from 1 to whatever, so he just plugged in 100 and found the answer".

Comment: In first or second grade, one of the chairs was coming loose, and nobody could turn the Allen wrench. I said it would work better if the short end went in the hexagonal screwhead and we turned the long end. This worked, but there have been no requests for interviews. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_key

Comment: @WillJagy I think you have to be an accomplished mathematician first for journals to publish anecdotes from your childhood. Ironically, if you're an accomplished mathematician, I imagine you have more interesting things to talk about.

Comment: @WillJagy you should probably edit the wiki to reflect the noted historical hex key event. We have to take an active role in telling our story.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook, that would make the most sense.

Comment: I would say that the challenge of this problem is not about "what a 12-year-old knows", the challenge is to notice that after noon it took them 4 hours and 9 hours to cover the distance between A and B together and before noon when they were working together perfectly, it took them the "average" of 4 hours and 9 hours. Only, that now, you have to explain in an intuitive and simple way why this average should be the geometric mean.

Comment: Previously asked at http://mathoverflow.net/q/153185/12357

Comment: I don't think this is anything "that much" challenging. I knew quadratic formula when I was 7 or 8 and derived a version of Lagrange's solution to cubic equation at 11, so definitely Arnold, who solved Hilbert's $13$th problem (heptic equation! Fun, fun!), would have easily solved this one.

Comment: @BalarkaSen: Nevertheless, Arnold was very excited when he managed to solve it, according to the interview!

Comment: One possible issue with the presented solutions that came to my mind was: how do you know that sunrise is at the same time in both places? If $A$ and $B$ are in different time zones, then they could both leave at "sunrise" but still leave at different absolute moments in time...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Triangle similarity

He could have solved the question by drawing a figure such as the one below. If he knew about similar triangles at the age of $12$, he could easily set up the equation $ \dfrac{x}{4} = \dfrac{9}{x} $. From here, if he knew how to solve equations like this, he could solve $ x^2=36 $. If he did not, he could simply try a few different values of $x$ until he found one that works.

[image]

Colored triangles are similar. The problems with this explanation are:

- This is essentially drawing a time-position plot. Since this is a $12$ year old who does not know multivariate algebra, it's a bit of a stretch to assume he would know how to use kinematic plots to solve problems. But then again, who knows, maybe he was imagining the women walk and the plot seemed intuitive.
- It requires him to be able to set up and somehow find the solution of the quadratic equation.
- What does this have to do with "scaling arguments, dimensional analysis or toric variety theory"?

### Trial and error

He could have simply tried a bunch of possible values until he found a solution.

Let's say he decided to try $9$ am: That means woman $A$ walked the first distance in $3$. So the ratio of distances is $\dfrac{3}{4}$. But if woman $B$ walked the first part in $3$ hours, then the ratio comes out $$\dfrac{3}{9+3}=\dfrac{3}{12}!$$ So $9$ am isn't right.

Luckily the solution is an integer, and somewhere between $4$ and $9$ hours before noon, since the quick woman would have walked more than half the distance in the morning and the slow one would have walked less than half (drawing a $1$D diagram makes this obvious). Even if the solution was not an integer, after exhausting integers he could have tried half hours, then quarter hours, and so on. I'm sure a binary search type of strategy would become obvious if he kept track of how much each sunrise hour was off by. Since he spent "all day" on it, there's plenty of time for numeric solutions.

The problem is that solving it by brute force teaches you absolutely nothing (well, it's arithmetic practice, and you do end up discovering binary search). There's also the question of what this has to do with scaling arguments, dimensional analysis or toric variety theory. It's also the sort of solution that you would expect from perhaps a future clerk, not mathematician.

Incidentally, after trying a bunch of numbers like this, the $\dfrac{x}{4}=\dfrac{9}{x}$ equation does suggest itself.

### Sort of trial and error

It's not too great a leap to realize that the distance itself doesn't matter, so let's say he decided to let it be 50 km. Then the speed of woman $A$ is $\dfrac{50}{x+4}$. The speed of woman $B$ is $\dfrac{50}{x+9}$. We know that the ratio of their speed must be $\dfrac{x}{9}$ based on how long it took both women to walk the distance between $A$ and the meeting point. So $\dfrac{\dfrac{50}{x+4}}{\dfrac{50}{x+9}} = \dfrac{9}{x}$ which after some basic manipulation simplifies also to $x^2=36$. When the $50$s cancel, he would see right away that his hunch about distance not mattering was correct.

The problem with this is that requires a $12$ year old to reason about kinematics (ratio of speeds from ratio of times, deriving speed from time and distance) without having the mathematical vocabulary for doing so. It also requires him to not be daunted by the ugly looking equations that come out. Last, it requires him to have a hunch about the distance, otherwise he has to use a variable to represent distance and at that point we are back at multivariate algebra.

This method also does not appear to have anything to do with scaling arguments, dimensional analysis, or toric variety theory, except perhaps in the slightest sense.

### Conclusion

None of these options really satisfy me. For instance, I can't really imagine myself using any of these solutions when I was $12$. The only one I would have comprehended would be the straight trial and error, which I would have been too lazy to actually carry out. Though then again, I was never very good at math.

The problem seems to be a simple linear equation system, so I don't see what it has to do with the concepts he refers to. Perhaps he was making a metaphorical point about how this sort of problem is the "tip of the iceberg" of linear algebra that children first get exposed to? Or perhaps he actually figured out linear equations over the course of that day, and that was the revelation?

Comment: As I say in my comment on the question, similar triangles, the quadratic formula, and these sort of kinematic arguments were known to the average russian schoolboy of 12. Since Arnold was, um, a little above average, I don't see any problem, though do wonder what the hell he was talking about.

Comment: Note that you do not need this questionable bound on sunrise times because you know that the women started sometime between 4 and 9 hours before noon, this restricts the integer values for sunrise to the four values $4,5,6,7$.

Comment: @IgorRivin Well, that's a fair point. I also think it's likely that at least some Soviet schools thought the algebra at that level. But like I said in another comment, if he had already been taught how to solve it, why would he mention it in the interview, and say it came as a revelation?

Comment: @Phira You're right, I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 7):

The same without geometry:

Woman $w_{AB}$ did in $4$ hours what woman $w_{BA}$ did in $x$ hours, and woman $w_{BA}$ did in $9$ hours what woman $w_{AB}$ did in $x$ hours. Therefore woman $w_{AB}$ in $36=9\cdot 4$ hours walks as far as woman $w_{BA}$ walks in $9\cdot x$ hours, and for this distance woman $w_{AB}$ needs $x\cdot x$ hours. It follows that $x^2=36$, or $x=6$.

Answer (score 1):

Join the points A and B.
If the two women start back to back at the point AB of the resulting circle, they will meet at the corners of an equilateral triangle if one woman walks twice as fast as the other and stops walking when she meets the other woman again at AB.

But the "twice (as fast)" is in the given problem unknown, say (n-1) (the number of meeting points is then n).
This unknown n is related to 'the' unknown x in two ways :

9 *hours* / (n-1) =  4 *hours* (n-1) = x *hours*
or 
n = 5/2 and x = 6

Composing this equation is actually the hard part, hence the lack of explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The distance each woman walks after noon is the distance the other woman has walked from dawn till noon. The two ratios “distance walked before noon : distance walked after noon” are therefore reciprocal.
But since each woman’s speed is constant, the ratios are equal to the ratios “duration of walk before noon : duration of walk after noon”, i.e. x:4 and x:9 respectively.
Hence (x/4)(x/9)=1, whence x=6. The sun rose 6 hours before noon.
Almost no algebra, and nothing a bright 12-year-old wouldn’t know!

Answer (score 0):

A trivial solution: system of equations

Call $|AB|=L$, speed of first lady $v_1$, speed of second lady $v_2$ and time passes from dawn to $4pm$ as $t$.

Then we have $4$ equation with $4$ unknown.

$$4v_1+9v_2=L \tag1$$$$ (v_1+v_2)(t-4)=L \tag2$$$$ v_1 t=L\tag 3$$$$ v_2 (t+5)=L\tag 4$$

Answer (score -3):

Arnold said his solution was based on what  are “now called scaling arguments” and “came as a revelation.”
Did Arnold draw something like this?[straight line with points A, P and P creating "fractions" t over 9 and 4 over t](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z71VH.png)

Since the women (lets call them Ekaterina and Yelena) are walking at constant velocity v_Y=k v_E. Rearranging, v_Y/v_E =k.  Then from the diagram, or otherwise, t/9=4/t  . Hence t^2=36 and t = 6.   Sunrise occurs 6 hours before noon, that is  06.00 or 6 am. (Actually I have omitted one step (AP/t)/(AP/9)=(PB/4)/(PB/t), but this seems trivial.)